# MobileSingleStickControlの速度制御について(unity ver5.1.3f1)

Tags: c#

Androidでゲームを作り、最終調整に入っているのですが
上記のジョイスティックを使用し、移動したら早すぎるので、速度をもう少しゆっくりにしたいのですがどのうようにすればようですか？

ちなみにこのように記述しております。

```
vector.x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal") ;
vector.z = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical") ;
```

Comment: 入力値に1未満の定数を掛け算をすればいいんじゃないでしょうか

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ずっと難しく考えすぎていたようで、簡単に解決することができました。

Answer (score 0):

入力値に `1` 未満の定数を掛け算をすればよいと思います。

---

*この投稿は [@pgrho さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16808/mobilesinglestickcontrol%e3%81%ae%e9%80%9f%e5%ba%a6%e5%88%b6%e5%be%a1%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6unity-ver5-1-3f1#comment15382_16808) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*